# Is it possible to set (us, intl., with dead keys) keyboard layout as the spanish input method

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

My system is installed in English as my native langue is English; however, sometimes I need to be able to write in Spanish or other langues. Likewise my keyboard is a US Keyboard.

This creates an interesting predicament as I am able to set my keyboard layout to English(us, intl.,with dead keys) which helps with writing things such as my last name "Ocañas" in English. However, this also means my system is expecting me to type English and labels anything written in Spanish as a typo.

When I go to set my keyboard as (us, intl.,with dead keys) for Spanish the option is not present, so while I can set an input method of Spanish resolving the "typos" I am unable to type correctly because I do not have a Latin American keyboard.

For example, when I was daily driving windows(I prefer Ubuntu) I was able to set my input methods to English(US-international) and Spanish(Us-international) which allowed me to seamlessly switch between langues using super + space while effectively keeping the same keyboard.

Is it possible to Set Spanish(US., Intl., with dead keys) on Ubuntu (I'm running 23.04).

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: I have a feeling that your actual concern is spell checking. Please note that you can install e.g. the `hunspell-es` package and then switch between English and Spanish spellchecking as you like. That is unrelated to which keyboard layout you use.